# How do I simplify a fraction with a square root on the numerator?

Tags: calculus

How do I simplify this fraction :

$$\frac{(3x^2+4x)\sqrt {x+1}}{2(x+1)^2}$$

The final result is $\frac{3x^2+4x} {2(x+1)^{3/2}}$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your questions.  People will be much more prone to read them if you do.  There's a tutorial at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Also this will remove ambiguities. (Is it $\sqrt{x}$ or $\sqrt{x+1}$, is it $3x^2+\frac{4x}{2(x+1)^{3/2}}$ or $\frac{3x^2+4x}{2(x+1)^{3/2}}$ etc.)

Comment: I edited what I can. Now please make sure everything is correct and fix if necessary.

Comment: It's the square root of x+1

Comment: @SaraSalvante Clearly, there is a mistake and the term $3x^2$ should be multiplied by $\sqrt{x+1}$ as well.

Comment: I don't think there is a mistake...

Comment: It might be
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\color{red}{(3x^2+4x)}\sqrt {x+1}}{2(x+1)^2}=\frac{3x^2+4x} {2(x+1)^{3/2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Can you let me know when you have a stable edit ?

Comment: Yes i'm sorry its like that !! Can you please explain ?? Thank you!

Comment: I'm new hear and i don't really understand how to write them properly

Comment: Divide the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{x+1}$.

Comment: How do i accept an answer? I am not able to find the check mark anywhere

Comment: You need someone to submit an answer, in order that there is an answer for you to accept ... My previous comment & @JohnDoe  'sexplanation hardly amount to an answer ? ... My kindest regards DS $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

You divide the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt{x+1}$, which gives the desired result.